# Marketing Cloud Syncrhonization Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

The records from a couple of Salesforce entities are not entering to the SFMC data sources in Contact Builder. Although the entity >Contact< is working Ok with 100K contacts, the entities that are not syncing well are:

-Campaing Member: there is 1M records and only 100K are retrieved
-Custom Object: there are 100k sync and it should be 200K.

Support said to upgrade the connector but it didn´t work out.

Comment: Try clearing your token

Comment: token clearing is useful for many cases, thanks! in this case, it is a backend problem of the plaform.  Thanks very much though.

Comment: @Daniel could you elaborate on your solution?